# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Quota exceeded

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Estou tendo um problema com meu service-worker. De repente ele começou a mostrar esse erro no devtools:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Quota exceeded.
```

Segue meu **service-worker.js**:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

if( 'function' === typeof importScripts) {
  importScripts("{% static 'js/cache-polyfill.js' %}");
  self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
      caches.open('myweb').then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll([
          "/",
          "{% static 'assets/css/all.css' %}",
          "{% static 'assets/js/all.js' %}",
        ]);

      })
    );
  });
  self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    var body_content = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
    const title = body_content.title;
    const options = {
      body: body_content.text,
      icon: body_content.icon,
      badge: body_content.icon,
      data: {
        url: body_content.url
      }
    };
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
  });
  self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(
      clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url)
    );
  });


  self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.open('myweb').then(function(cache) {
        return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
        });
      })
    );
  });
}
```